# Return only results where every iteration from another table exists in source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with an application that has the following two Microsoft SQL tables:

```
Object Access
    UserID
    CompanyID
    ObjectID


Company
    CompanyID
```

The Object Access table holds all user -> company -> object access combinations, the Company tables holds a list of companies. The user can have access to an object in multiple companies. There is a FK between the Companies table and Access table on the CompanyID field.

So sample data would look like:

```
Object Access
    UserID    CompanyID    ObjectID
    Bob       ABC          Acct
    Bob       DEF          Acct
    Bob       ABC          Vend
    Dan       ABC          Acct


Company
    CompanyID
    ABC
    DEF
```

I am looking for a query that returns only the results where the user has access to an object **in all companies**.

So results from the data above would be:

```
UserID    ObjectID
Bob       Acct
```

As this is the only user -> object assignment that exists in all companies.

Basically I'm trying to figure out which users have access to an object in all companies (and then do the reverse to see which users have access to objects in only certain companies)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user has access to all companies for a given Object type, then the number of records for the (`UserID`, `ObjectID`) combination in the Object Access table will equal the number of companies in the Company table.  So to get all such combinations, we can use:

```
SELECT USERID, OBJECTID FROM OBJECTACCESS
GROUP BY USERID, OBJECTID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COMPANYID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPANY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
    a.*,
    (select count(*) from company) as company_cnt
from
    object_access a
where
    company_cnt = (select count(*) from object_access b where b.UserID = a.UserID and b.ObjectID = :p_object_id)
```